# Issue with webview scenario in fragment

Tags: android

New to android, please excuse if any mistakes

Issue with FiveFragment.java ,where **mWebview** varible is underlined in red,"cannot resolve symbol mWebview"

frament_five.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ekatechhp.pkmapplication.FiveFragment">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

FragmentFive.java:

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class FiveFragment extends Fragment {
public FiveFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout. fragment_five, container, false);
    mWebview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebview.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: You are missing `private WebView mWebview;` as you need to declare mWebview so that it can be recognized by the compiler, add this above your constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare   **WebView** in your program like this  WebView mWebview;

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class FiveFragment extends Fragment {

WebView mWebview ;//declare here

public FiveFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout. fragment_five, container, false);
mWebview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebview.loadUrl("https://google.com");

// Enable Javascript
WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

// Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

return view;
  }
 }
```

and make sure ur import this

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't declare `mWebview` in your fragment.

Add `WebView mWebview;` to declare it.

Final code is -

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class FiveFragment extends Fragment {

WebView mWebview;

public FiveFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout. fragment_five, container, false);
    mWebview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebview.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return view;
}
}
```